# K8s rolling-update does not gracefully switch pods in load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When changing the image version of the web-deployment and triggering a rolling-update in a deployment with 1 replica an additional pod with the new version is created and running. But still the live pod is terminated before the load balancer seems to switch to the new pod.

Running `curl http://<Load Balancer Ingress IP>/mynode.test?[1-2000]` shows errors during the switching process.

I tried a few things which might have spoiled up the timing.

These are my yaml files and the gcloud commands:

```
gcloud container \
clusters create "sling-cluster-small" \
--project "devops-test" \
--zone "us-central1-a" \
--machine-type "g1-small" \
--num-nodes "3" \
--network "default"

gcloud compute disks create \
  --project "devops-test" \
  --zone "us-central1-a" \
  --size 200GB \
  mongo-disk
```

db-deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mongo-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: mongo-disk
            fsType: ext4
```

db-service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   name: mongo
 name: mongo
spec:
 ports:
   - port: 27017
     targetPort: 27017
 selector:
   name: mongo
```

web-deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
#  minReadySeconds: 60
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
# 0.1.2 and 0.2.2 are the two valid versions
      - image: sandroboehme/sample-app:0.1.2
#      - image: sandroboehme/sample-app:0.2.2
        name: web
        ports:
        - name: http-server
          containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /mynode.test
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          timeoutSeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 5
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              # A workaround to get 0% downtime during deploys. This should
              command: ["sh", "-c", "curl http://localhost:8080/mynode.test?ready=false -u admin:admin && sleep 15"]
```

web-service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: web
 labels:
   name: web
spec:
# type: NodePort
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
   - port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
     protocol: TCP
#     nodePort: 30000
 selector:
   name: web
```

How can one handle that?
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks for your time looking into this!

Comment: Service will only send traffic to pods that are ready (terminating pods aren't ready). Your web-deployment Deployment expects the system to terminate the old pod only after the new pod becomes ready. Which means the old pod won't be terminated before the service directs traffic to the new pod. Since the traffic is directed to the new pod as soon as the pod becomes ready (i.e. passed readiness probe), maybe the disruption is from the new pod? If so, you'd want to check if the readinessProbe is set properly.

Comment: Solved - the problem was, that curl kept the connection open to the terminating pod.

Comment: A better way of continuously testing requests is to use `watch` like this:
`watch "curl http://example.com/path"`